# Evaluating the indefinite integral $\int\frac{x\arctan x}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

The integral again is $$\int\frac{x\arctan x}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$$

I'm actually pretty much just stumped on this one. It looks like it should be amenable to a substitution kinda like $\arctan x$
but that obviously does not work.

I also thought maybe by parts, since 
$$
\int\frac{\arctan x}{1+x^2}dx
$$
Isn't too bad to anti differentiate but this approach seems to complicate things on the differentiation side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting $x=\tan\theta$ yields
$$ \int\frac{x\arctan x}{(1+x^2)^2}\;dx=\int\frac{\theta\tan\theta}{\sec^4\theta}\sec^2\theta\;d\theta=\int\theta\sin\theta\cos\theta\;d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\int\theta\sin(2\theta)\;d\theta$$
and this integral can be handled using integration by parts.

Comment: ah great, that works nicely!

Comment: @qbert A nice follow up question would be: What is the answer when you integrate from $x=0$ to infinity? Because that's a question in my calculus book, with exactly your integral...Think about it!

Comment: Interesting! Which book is it in?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way by direct integration by parts:

Let $u = \arctan x, dv = \frac{x}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$, then $du = \frac{1}{x^2+1}dx, v = -\frac{1}{2(x^2+1)}$.

Then  $$\int\frac{x\arctan x}{(1+x^2)^2}dx =-\frac{1}{2(x^2+1)}\arctan x+\int   \frac{1}{2(x^2+1)}\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx=\int   \frac{1}{2(x^2+1)^2}dx$$

Try some trigonometric subsititution for $\int   \frac{1}{2(x^2+1)^2}dx$